# How to extract data & convert rows to columns at the same time in SQL

Tags: sql, pivot

I have searched for a while. Although I have seen some examples, I haven't found anything that matches my case.

I was trying to extract data from a bigger table, but I also want to convert the rows and columns during the process. I have seen some answers that made me realize that I should probably rephrase my question. I dont know the values in testscore column, those just for example.

```
ID  testscore
1     x
2     x
3     x
4     x
```

into this

```
testscore1 testscore2 testscore3 testscore4
x          x           x           x



  select 
        max(case ID when 1 then testscore else 0 end) as testscore1,
        max(case ID when 2 then testscore else 0 end) as testscore2,
        max(case ID when 3 then testscore else 0 end) as testscore3,
        max(case ID when 4 then testscore else 0 end) as testscore4
        from testtable
```

does work, however it cant combine with other entries from the same table, but thx

Comment: ,Which database are you using..?

Comment: use PIVOT to conversion.

Comment: @Mansoor I was using Db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted answer for SQL server.Using PIVOT table

```
CREATE TABLE #Table(ID INT, testscore INT)

INSERT INTO #Table( ID ,testscore )
SELECT 1,96 UNION ALL
SELECT 2,94 UNION ALL
SELECT 3,97 UNION ALL
SELECT 4,91

SELECT *
FROM 
( 
 SELECT ID ,testscore
 FROM #Table
)A
PIVOT
(
  MAX(testscore) FOR ID IN ([1],[2],[3],[4])
) pvt
```

Edit : For Db try below query  :

```
 SELECT MAX(CASE ID WHEN 1 THEN testscore ELSE 0 END) AS testscore1,
 MAX(CASE ID WHEN 2 THEN testscore ELSE 0 END) AS testscore2,
 MAX(CASE ID WHEN 3 THEN testscore ELSE 0 END) AS testscore3,
 MAX(CASE ID WHEN 4 THEN testscore ELSE 0 END) AS testscore4
 FROM #Table
```

Comment: does work, however it cant combine with other entries from the same table, but thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form

```
select (select testscore from scores where id = 1) as testscore1,
(select testscore from scores where id = 2) as testscore2,
(select testscore from scores where id = 3) as testscore3,
(select testscore from scores where id = 4) as testscore4
```

I do not like it so much. But it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    select [1] as testscore1,[2] as testscore2,[3] as testscore3,[4] as testscore4
from 
(select  id,testscore from piv) p 
pivot
(max(testscore) for ID in ([1],[2],[3],[4])) as pvb
```

output

```
testscore1  testscore2  testscore3  testscore4
96            94          97         91
```